# Many inputs to one output with Mule DataMapper

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

Friends,

I have two inputs, A and B, both JSON.
I need to generate with DataMapper, a single output (custom) also in JSON format.

Example:

**My Input A:**

```
{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "age": "40"
}
```

**My Input B:**

```
{
    "country": "Brazil"
    "city": "Rio de Janeiro"
}
```

**My Custom Output:**

```
{
    "customerName": "John Doe",
    "customerAge": "40",
    "customerCountry": "Brazil",
    "customerCity": "Rio de Janeiro"
}
```

It can generate this output using the Mule DataMapper? How to?

At the time, I know use only one Input with DataMapper.

Comment: Eu posso utilizar outro compomente. Não é obrigatório ser DataMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take one of the input as the payload and the other as the variable.

My Payload was

{
 "name": "John Doe",
 "age": "40"
}

My Variable was

{
    "country": "Brazil"
    "city": "Rio de Janeiro"
}

Please find the below sample that I tested and works.

```
 <flow name="combineFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/testings" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <logger message="Coming here " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <set-variable variableName="mypayload"
        value="{&quot;country&quot;: &quot;Brazil&quot;,&quot;city&quot;: &quot;Rio de Janeiro&quot;}"
        doc:name="Variable" mimeType="application/json" />

    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
   %output application/json
    ---

{
"customerName": payload.name,
"customerAge": payload.age,
"customerCountry": flowVars.mypayload.country,
"customerCity": flowVars.mypayload.city
}]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>

</flow>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Slightly similar with previous answer: you need to take one input as payload and another one as variable.

Following is the implementation using DataMapper (not DataWeave/Transform Message)

**XML**:

```
<flow name="genericFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dm" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="POST"/>
    <set-variable variableName="inputB"
        value="#['{&quot;country&quot;: &quot;Brazil&quot;, &quot;city&quot;: &quot;Rio de Janeiro&quot;}']" mimeType="application/json"
        doc:name="Input B" />
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="JSON_To_JSON" doc:name="JSON To JSON">
        <data-mapper:input-arguments>
            <data-mapper:input-argument key="inputBjson">#[new org.json.JSONObject(flowVars.inputB)]</data-mapper:input-argument>
        </data-mapper:input-arguments>
    </data-mapper:transform>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo" />
</flow>
```

**GRF**:

```
...
<Dictionary>
<Entry id="DictionaryEntry0" input="true" name="inputPayload" output="false" type="object"/>
<Entry id="DictionaryEntry1" input="false" name="outputPayload" output="true" type="object"/>
<Entry dictval.__javaType="org.json.JSONObject" id="DictionaryEntry2" input="true" name="inputBjson" output="false" type="object"/>
</Dictionary>
...
<attr name="melScript"><![CDATA[//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.customerName = input.name;
output.customerAge = input.age;
output.customerCountry = inputArguments.inputBjson.getString("country");
output.customerCity = inputArguments.inputBjson.getString("city");]]></attr>
```

Notes: input B is registered to DataMapper as Input Argument with Type = Object (MEL only), and its class is: `org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

One input give it as payload and other one use message properties and store the second input values as variable.Now inside data mapper use the variable in input argument field and map it.Simple!! hope it helps.